# CSS: How to differentiate between two same tags without a class?

Tags: html, css

my problem is that I got a xml file which got two times the same tag but with different content. How could I use differentiate between those two without a class?

Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" media="screen"/> 
<mytest>
    <mystory>
        <myItem>
            <myDescription>Hello my name is <myName>Frosta</myName></myDescription>
        </myItem>
        <myItem>
            <myDescription>Hello my name is <myName>Frosti</myName></myDescription>
        </myItem>
    </mystory>
</mytest>
```

Comment: Tried `:nth-*` selectors?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: yes I tried that but it didn't work... it is the newsitem tag to be specific. But well maybe it is because I use CSS for just a day and did something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use the `:nth-of-type()` CSS selector. It will select the nth item of whatever element is passed ahead of the colon. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

```
section > newsItem:nth-of-type(1) {
    /* Styles For First newsItem */
}

section > newsItem:nth-of-type(2) {
    /* Styles For Second newsItem */
}
```

If you know exactly how many children you'll have *in addition to* the `newsItem`s then you could also use `:nth-child()` but `:nth-of-type()` is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understood what tag are you targeting, but maybe you could use something like [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to do the trick.

Comment: It was  the newsitem tag...  And I put it in my post originally but I don't know why now it isn't in my post... well